# TYPO3: Is there an option to enable non-admin users to edit the "url segment" textfield?

Tags: configuration, typo3, content-management-system, typo3-10.x, user-administration

I have a TYPO3 v10.4.15 installation. In there, for some reason, only my "Admin" users have access to the "URL segment" field, where users can define or update the route to the page they are editing.

EDIT PAGE "MyPage"
Text fields:
Title
Page Title
URL Segment <----------------------------------- this field is missing for non-admins
Alternative Navigation Title
Subtitle

Is there an option to enable this for non-admins?

I know there are [TSConfig options](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/10.4/en-us/UserTsconfig/Options.html?highlight=options) to enable non-admins to flush the CMS cache (enabling the lighting icon in the backend), an option for non-admin-users to use the "Import" context menu (to import .t3d files), and option to use the file upload feature:

```
options.defaultUploadFolder = 1:
options.impexp.enableImportForNonAdminUser = 1
options.clearCache.pages = 1
# magic option to enable URL Segment field = ??
```

Perhaps there is a similar option to edit URL segments, and I just did not see it? Or some other parameter? It does not have to be an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are so-called "Excluded fields" in TYPO3, you have to give permission to access it for non-admins. You can control those fields within user group settings.

1. Create a backend user group or edit the existing one, probably at the page with uid `0` (in the same place where backend users are stored).
2. In this group go to the `Access Lists` tab, scroll down, open the `Page`
   pane and find checkbox with label: `URL Segment (slug) [pages:slug]`

   - switch it **on**
3. Switch on another required fields (also in other tables/record types)
4. Add this new group to the user who's non-admin.

More about excluded fields:

- for admins: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/master/en-us/UserManagement/GroupPermissions/Index.html
- for devs: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/Columns/Properties/Exclude.html